# joomla multilanguage website redirect to http:/// only in IE in home

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla2.5, multilingual

I made a website with joomla 2.5, and it's multilingual (native feature)

It works great on every browsers and mobile device. But on IE only the website redirect to a blank page with address bar displaying
    http : ///

Nothing else, no error, nothing. just that redirect.

the problem regarding the redirect from www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/it and www.mydomain.com/en

this happen only in home page

All the other pages works correctly ( example: www.mydomain.com/en/hello etc. )

i'm using the standard joomla multilanguage feature

any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? Redirect from where? Main url? Please provide more information

Comment: when you go on my website only in Internet Explorer it redirect to http:///. there's no redirect activated.

Comment: Please provide a url. Is http:/// the full url shown in the address bar? Other browsers like Mozilla, Chrome, Opera work fine?

Comment: the website works great with every browsers and mobile too, but IE gives me that redirect. The full url is "http:///".

Comment: We'll need some code or a demo if you want help.

Comment: the website is emotionsinpuglia.com/welcome

Comment: Hi, is there a reason why you are redirecting to the welcome directory  instead of simply serving the site from emotionsinpuglia.com/en or emotionsinpuglia.com/it?

Comment: yes,there will be another website and a switch for languange..

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. To clarify, eventually, instead of redirecting from emotionsinpuglia.com --> emotionsinpuglia.com/welcome you will have a standalone site or page at emotionsinpuglia.com? If yes, can you post the specifics of how you are managing the redirection at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and i want to share it with you all

System - Language Filter cause an error only in home when it switch to the default language.

example: from domainname to domainname/en

Just set "remove default prefix" to "yes" (in the plugin option) and the homepage will work correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the way you are redirecting from root --> root/welcome. Can you post specifics of how you are doing this?

Comment: the issue regarding the redirect of multilanguage from  down vote accept
 

I suspect the problem is in the way you are redirecting from  emotionsinpuglia.com/welcome to emotionsinpuglia.com/welcome/it and emotionsinpuglia.com/welcome/en